# Validate Date in Powerapps when overlaps

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps-formula

How can I validate my Task Start Date in PowerApps with other Start Dates in the list of Tasks - not to overlap!
So I need Detect conflict in Start date in PowerApps

Do I need to go in List Validation (do the validation od start date) or maybe I need a peace of code in PowerApps